# Long format in descriptive statistic table using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics

I am trying to get a statistic descriptive table in a long format using dplyr. I did try with gather but it dont work... an example of my code:

```
data(mtcars)

table=mtcars %>% 
summarise_all(funs(mean, sd,median, min, max))
dim(table)

[1]  1 55

table[1:4,1:4]

>      mpg_mean cyl_mean disp_mean  hp_mean
1    20.09062   6.1875  230.7219 146.6875
NA         NA       NA        NA       NA
NA.1       NA       NA        NA       NA
NA.2       NA       NA        NA       NA

table2=mtcars %>% 
gather(stat) %>%
summarise_all(funs(mean, sd,median, min, max))
dim(table2)
table2[1:4,1:4]

1: In mean.default(stat) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
3: In mean.default(sort(x, partial = half + 0L:1L)[half + 0L:1L]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
> [1]  1 10
>      stat_mean value_mean stat_sd value_sd
1           NA   39.60853      NA 84.20792
NA          NA         NA      NA       NA
NA.1        NA         NA      NA       NA
NA.2        NA         NA      NA       NA
```

I have in my mind get something like for each statistic :

```
          mean    
mpg    20.09062   
cyl     6.1875    
disp    230.7219  
hp      146.6875
```

## EDIT:

here I add a real example of my dataframe, removing dots and _ previosly I think that its easier for solution below:

ex= data.frame(title_one=c(11, 22,34,22,43,454 ), title.two=c(22,44,343,3434,424,676), title3=c(6, 1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ))

```
names(ex) = gsub(pattern = "_*", replacement = "", x = names(ex)) 
names(ex) = gsub(pattern = ".", replacement = "", x = names(ex), fixed = TRUE)  

 table = ex %>%
   summarise_all(funs( min, max,mean, sd))

  gather(table) %>%
   separate(key, into = c("key1", 'key2')) %>%
   spread(key2, value)

  > + +       key1  max       mean min          sd
  1   title3    6   1.666667   0    2.160247
  2 titleone  454  97.666667  11  174.915599
  3 titletwo 3434 823.833333  22 1302.072873
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `gather` into 'long' format, `separate` the 'key' into two columnss and `spread` it to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(table) %>%
    separate(key, into = c("key1", 'key2')) %>%
    spread(key2, value)
```

---

For the updated dataset with multiple delimiter, we could use `extract` to capture the characters

```
gather(table) %>%
    extract(key, into = c("key1", "key2"), "^(\\w+)[_.](.*)") %>% 
    spread(key2, value)
```

Comment: Thanks, work great with the example but lamentably I got a error with my real data: Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 35 rows:

Comment: @Rodrigo. Okay, got the error issue.  Initially, i had take care of that by adding `gather(table) %>% separate(key, into = c("key1", 'key2")) %>% %>%group_by(key1, key2) %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% spread(key2, value)` then realized, here it is not needed as there are no dupese

Comment: Thanks, work good with few variables, but with my entire dataset not, appear variables names in column and statistic names in row...

Comment: @Rodrigo. Do you have `_` in column names i..e mutiple `_`

Comment: @Rodrigo. Could you please update your post with a minimal example that reproduce the issue

Comment: @Rodrigo. Updated the post.  Also, if there are dupes, then you sshould usee the sequence creation as earlier

Comment: Really thanks for your time and effort, lamentably I have the same error... I remove dots and _ from my col names and fix the problem names(bd) = gsub(pattern = "_*", replacement = "", x = names(bd))
names(bd) = gsub(pattern = ".", replacement = "", x = names(bd), fixed = TRUE)

Comment: @Rodrigo. Could be that the orginal dataset column patterns are more complex.  Is it now fixed?.  In the extract step, we are matching a word as a group (`\\w+`) followed by either dot or `_` and capture the second set of characters.  so, if your dataset column have other delimiters, you may have to specify there in the `[._]`

Comment: using dataframe: "ex" from update I have wrong columns names, dont exist more complex patterns but changing col names removing dots and _ your solution works great!!